# Left Self Join return one row per 'primary'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Rel_Id  Last    First   Relation
1   Jones   John    Primary
1   Jones   Mary    Spouse
1   Jones   Carl    Dependent
2   Will    Bill    Primary
3   Fine    Howard  Primary
4   Smith   Diana   Primary
4   Smith   Axel    Spouse
```

I am trying to return ALL "Primary" relations, one per row, but include the Spouse on the same row IF there is one.

The results I would like to achieve would look like this:

```
1   Jones   John    Primary Jones   Mary    Spouse
2   Will    Bill    Primary null    null    null
3   Fine    Howard  Primary null    null    null
4   Smith   Diana   Primary Smith   Axel    Spouse
```

or this would be okay too:

```
1   Jones   John    Primary Jones   Mary    Spouse
2   Will    Bill    Primary Will    Bill    Primary
3   Fine    Howard  Primary Fine    Howard  Primary
4   Smith   Diana   Primary Smith   Axel    Spouse
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT
P.Rel_Id,
P.Last,
P.`First`,
P.Relation,
S.Last AS sLast,
S.`First` AS sFirst,
S.Relation AS sRelation
FROM
relations AS P
LEFT JOIN relations AS S ON S.Rel_Id = P.Rel_Id
WHERE P.Relation = 'Primary' 
AND S.Relation <> 'Dependent'
```

The above query results in:

```
1   Jones   John    Primary Jones   John    Primary
1   Jones   John    Primary Jones   Mary    Spouse
2   Will    Bill    Primary Will    Bill    Primary
3   Fine    Howard  Primary Fine    Howard  Primary
4   Smith   Diana   Primary Smith   Diana   Primary
4   Smith   Diana   Primary Smith   Axel    Spouse
```

Unfortunately, my query while correctly excluding 'Dependent" shows two rows for unique 'Primary' members where there is a Spouse, which I do not want. How can I return one row per 'Primary' relation only with a Spouse if there is one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems so obvious now - and so simple!
(Thanks all - really)

```
SELECT
P.Rel_Id,
P.Last,
P.`First`,
P.Relation,
S.Rel_Id AS sRel_Id,
S.Last AS sLast,
S.`First` AS sFirst,
S.Relation AS sRelation
FROM
relations AS P
LEFT JOIN relations AS S ON S.Rel_Id = P.Rel_Id and S.Relation = 'Spouse'
WHERE P.Relation = 'Primary'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional check in your query in the join condition so that two Primary are not shown and only spouse is shown.

So add this condition as well in the query:

```
S.Relation <> P.Relation
```

So the final query would become:

```
SELECT
P.Rel_Id,
P.Last,
P.`First`,
P.Relation,
S.Last AS sLast,
S.`First` AS sFirst,
S.Relation AS sRelation
FROM
relations AS P
LEFT JOIN relations AS S ON S.Rel_Id = P.Rel_Id AND S.Relation <> P.Relation
WHERE P.Relation = 'Primary' 
AND S.Relation <> 'Dependent'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but that only returns the two rows where there is a spouse. I need those as well as the rows where there is no spouse. See my two examples of returned data above.

Comment: ok got your point. Have you tried using GROUP BY last, first at the end of your query?

Comment: Can't Group By last, first as those are not unique and will produce erroneous results. Tried Group By Rel_Id but that just grabs the first 'Relation' value, not necessarily 'Spouse'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',
                               last, first, relation),
                     SEPARATOR ' -- '
                     ORDER BY IF(relation = 'PRIMARY', 0, rel_id)
        ) AS Family
    FROM relations
    GROUP BY last;
```

It does not give you "columns" like you asked for, but it might do.

This will handle families with any number of persons.  However, it depends on `last` being unique.  (That is an existing flaw in your schema design.)

Separating out the `last` might be better:

```
SELECT  last,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',
                               first, relation),
                     SEPARATOR ' -- '
                     ORDER BY IF(relation = 'PRIMARY', 0, rel_id)
        ) AS Family
    FROM relations
    GROUP BY last;
```

Comment: Last isn't unique but Rel_Id is - to a particular family. I do need columns though. Your answer errors out with a: Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPARATOR ' -- '
                     ORDER BY IF(relation = 'PRIMARY', NULL, r' at line 4

Comment: This gives me the correct results, but I still need the columns: SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' ', last, first, relation)
ORDER BY IF(relation = 'PRIMARY', 0, rel_id)
SEPARATOR ' --- ')
AS Family
FROM relations
WHERE Relation <> 'Dependent'
GROUP BY rel_id

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Dependent exclusion.